# Is "$a^p + b^p = c^p + d^p \Rightarrow (a+b) \equiv (c+d) \mod p$" true?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

> Is $$a^p + b^p = c^p + d^p \implies (a+b) \equiv (c+d) \mod p$$ true?

Let $a,b,c,d$ be (distinct) positive integers, and $p$ be prime.  My reasoning is roughly as follows:
$$(a^p + b^p) \equiv (a^p \mod p + b^p \mod p) \mod p$$
then by Fermat's Little Theorem
$$(a^p + b^p) \equiv (a \mod p + b \mod p) \mod p$$
$$\Rightarrow (a^p + b^p) \equiv (a + b) \mod p$$
and similarly
$$(c^p + d^p) \equiv (c+d) \mod p.$$
If $a^p+b^p=c^p+d^p$ then clearly $(a^p+b^p) \equiv (c^p+d^p) \mod p$, and hence (less clearly), $(a+b) \equiv (c+d) \mod p$.

EDIT: the motivation for this question is an efficient algorithm to search for Taxicab(5,2,2).

Comment: Yes, it looks good to me.

Comment: The converse is certainly not true in general. Consider $a=1,b=3,c=d=2,p=7$, Then, $a+b\equiv 4\equiv c+d\pmod{p}$ but $a^7+b^7=1+3^7$ whereas $c^7+d^7=2^7+2^7=2^8$ and they are certainly not equal. However, they are congruent modulo $p$, so the converse holds in $\Bbb Z_p$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found another nice proof of this fact (for n = 5, but can "easily" be generalised to all $p$): by the binomial theorem,
$$(a+b)^5 = a^5 + 5a^4b + 10a^3b^2 + 10a^2b^3 + 5ab^4 + b^5$$
which can be rearranged to show that
$$a^5+b^5 = (a+b)^5 - 5(a^4b + 2a^2b^3 + 2a^3b^2 + ab^4)$$
$$\Rightarrow a^5 + b^5 \equiv (a+b)^5 \mod 5$$
$$\therefore a^5 + b^5 \equiv c^5 + b^5 \mod 5 \Rightarrow (a+b)^5 \equiv (c+d)^5 \mod 5$$

Answer (score 2):

This is perfectly fine,  the only detail is that you absolutely don't need the four integers to be distinct, they could be anything.